# Get rho and theta with miximum votes from cv2.HoughLines

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform, accumulator

I would like to use `cv2.HoughLines` to get the pair of `(rho, theta)`, which has most votes from the voting matrix.
The function

```
cv2.HoughLines(Canny2h_upper,1,np.pi/180,500)
```

returns a list of `(rho, theta)` values.
My assumption:

```
cv2.HoughLines(Canny2h_upper,1,np.pi/180,500)[0][0]
```

returns the pair of `(rho,theta)` with maximum votes.
My question:
Is the assumption true?
Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, lines in output are sorted by number of votes in descending order. So the first line in output has maximum votes. It was made for performance reasons.

But be careful, since this feature is not [documented](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#houghlines). Some implementation of HoughLines algorithm (for example for GPU) may output lines in different order.